# Parse.com: set Date as data type not current date

Tags: date, parse-platform

I have Date data and converted to string "2014-04-16 08:27:52" from my local PostgreSQL.

Please explain me how to set it at Parse.com as Date datatype?

Answer (score 2):

In the docs on rest API search on date and see the json type and format :

"__type":"Date","iso":"2011-08-21T18:02:52

That would be Included in the date elements json used in the post.

Comment: i 'm sorry i use js api

Comment: OK just format an iso-8859 date string as an arg to Date()

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out:

```
var date = new Date("2014-04-16 08:27:52");
object.set("last_update",date);
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can do:

```
$parse->someDate = $parse->dataType( 'date', '1985-01-01' );
```

In JavaScript, you can do:

```
var someDate = new Date("1985-01-01");
yourclass.set( 'someDate', { "__type": "Date", "iso": someDate.toISOString() } );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. but my question is about Parse.Com set Date and not parse the date at php. I've answer it and my question was solved

Answer (score 0):

For Parse.com and PHP, the answer is less straight forward than what is presented here. It took me a while to figure out that `dataType()` isn't working for some reason in the SDK.

It seems many people got the `$parse->dataType()` syntax [from here](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/07/03/parse-com-using-datatypes-pointers-and-acl-in-php-and-javascript/). But I can't find this function anymore in the official SDK.

Then there is [this bug](https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library/issues/135) and the [resulting function from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876860/php-parse-com-parsequery-between-createdat), but neither of these are very user friendly.

As it turns out, the Parse PHP SDK will handle an **array** for the value in the `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, and other special data types.

This code works (essentially a direct port from their REST API / JavaScript):

```
$query->greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", ["__type" => "Date", "iso" => date('Y-m-01\TH:i:s')]);
```

Feel free to use that format for other special types, like [GeoPoints](https://parse.com/docs/rest#geo).