# php parse.com parseQuery between createdAt

Tags: php, parse-platform

I using the PHP library for parse.com and I wanna do a filter between two dates compared with CreatedAt field, I'm trying to use:

```
$pqry->whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', $pqry->dataType('date', $startdate)) ;
$pqry->whereLessThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', $pqry->dataType('date', $enddate)) ;
//$startdate = '2014/07/21 00:00:00'; $endtdate = '2014/07/21 23:59:59';
```

but don't work, i found this code:

```
   public function whereBetweenOrEqualDates($key, $startDate, $endDate){
    if(isset($key) && isset($startDate) && isset($endDate)){
        $this->_query[$key] = array(
            '$gte' => $startDate,
            '$lte' => $endDate
        );
    }
```

But don't work well, some one can tell me the best way to do this filter?

Regards

Comment: `"but don't work"` or `"But don't work well"` aren't good enough descriptions for the issues. What errors do you get?

Comment: hi @Darren, don't work is because don't apply the filter and no have a error message, for that I ask for a correct way to do that filter, thanks in advance if you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it helps anyone, the code:

```
public function whereBetweenOrEqualDates($key, $startDate, $endDate){
if(isset($key) && isset($startDate) && isset($endDate)){
    $this->_query[$key] = array(
        '$gte' => $startDate,
        '$lte' => $endDate
    );
}
```

Works fine for between filter, the format for the date need send in a ISO, like:

```
//$startdate = '2014-07-21T00:00:00Z-6'; $endtdate = '2014-07-21T23:59:59Z-6';
```

The Z-6 is my timezone, the parse.com default is Z0 then you need save your dates with this format and request with this format to, this solved my problem.